# Any websites using Fabricjs with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I plan on creating an online picture collage maker using fabric.js with angular.js. However, being new to both technologies, I have spent the past couple of weeks getting myself acquainted with both fabric.js and angular.js. To wrap up what I have been learning, I have been searching the net for any website that uses fabric.js as an angular module, but so far, the best that I have seen is [angular-fabric](https://github.com/michaeljcalkins/angular-fabric) which is quite good but not what am looking for (I can't even get the example they provided to work properly on localhost without it throwing some dependency exceptions). Can someone please share a link to a live website that uses the aforementioned technologies for image editing (or any other function) as I believe I will learn a lot by inspecting how they structured their HTML markup

Comment: Doing so isn't allowed here and only attracts spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabrics own website combines Angular and Fabric

Comment: Here on Stackoverflow, we don't recommend off-site solutions (including websites). Please remove your answer but please also move your useful information to a comment under the question. That way we can close this off-topic question. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: @Darryl Hebbes Well thanks a lot for pointing me to that. I believe it would make my life a whole lot easier

Comment: Thanks @markE, and noted!

Comment: @markE I am unable to delete the answer once it's accepted.